# Highslide JS > Highchart - how do I modify?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How do I make this example http://www.highcharts.com/demo/?example=spline-plot-bands&theme=default, live, updating every second, just like in this example http://www.highcharts.com/demo/?example=dynamic-update&theme=default.

That first example, spline with plot bands, is exactly what I'm after; 2 plot graphs with an option to hide or show one or the other..
The only thing that's missing is making them live and updating every second like in the other example.

How could I possibly achieve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The live updating in the second one is done by adding a timer to the `load` event inside the `chart`

```
chart: {
    //...
    events: {
        load: function() {
            // set up the updating of the chart each second
            var series = this.series[0];
            setInterval(function() {
                var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                    y = Math.random();
                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

So, when the chart has finished loading, [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) is called and that calls the provided function every 1000 milliseconds (i.e. every second); the callback for `setInterval` simply adds a new point via [`series.addPoint`](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series-object).

All you need to do is add a `load` event handler that sets up an appropriate `setInterval` call to add your new points. In a more realistic case you'd use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) to launch an AJAX call to get more data, then in the AJAX's success callback, you'd add the new points and call `setTimeout` again to arrange for another AJAX call to be made after another second (or whatever time interval works in your application).

The [Highcharts documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/) looks fairly comprehensive and each example (of which there are many) has a convenient "view options" button for seeing the code so setting things up should be fairly straight forward with a bit of study.

Comment: how can i stop highcharts loading points is the new value is equal to the previous one??

Comment: @ivcode: I haven't touched Highcharts in awhile so I don't know, maybe ask a new question.

Comment: found a better charting library?